# Change style of UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, ios5, subclass, uialertview

I'm just a beginner when it comes to iOS programming.

I want to be able to change the style of a `UIAlertView`, for example change the color, make an image become the background of `UIAlertView` etc.
But I dont know how, please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the possible UIAlertView styles in the [UIAlertView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html). You can do a basic alert view, text entry, secure text entry, and login/password input. It is not very customisable. If you want to do a lot of customisation I suggest creating your own custom view and loading it.

**Edit to address comment**:

To create a custom view you create a UIView object:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
[self.view addSubView:myView];
```

This will add your new view as a subview of the parent view. You can then add other objects as subviews of your 'myView' object. For example a UIImageView to create a background image, or UIButtons to handle interaction like a UIAlertView.

If you want to do something like this you need to look through the documentation to figure out the specifics as you can do a lot of customisation like this.

Comment: I have not implemented a customized view yet. Could you show me some ways of view customization.